# Uploading images to Server Using php Form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to have the user upload an image to my server in a directory i created. The user uses a form to select the image and then I use a php code to upload the image to the directory "image/Profile_Pic/" as well as its location my database. But When i test my code, it always gives me that the file cannot be uploaded and nothing appears in my table in the user's data and i cant figure out why.

HTML FORM:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST"> 
        Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"><br>  
        <input type="submit" value="Add">  
</form>
```

UPLOAD.PHP:

```
<?php   
    session_start();
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $host_name = "";
    $user_name = "";
    $password = "";
    $db_name = "";
    $db_link = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error($db_link));

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//This is the directory where images will be saved  
$target = "image/Profile_Pic/";  
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);  


$target = $target . $_FILES['photo']['name'];   

//This gets all the other information from the form  
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);  

//Writes the information to the database  

$table_name = "User";
$query = "UPDATE $table_name SET Profile_Pic = '$pic' WHERE Username='$user';";
$result = mysqli_query($db_link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db_link));


//Writes the photo to the server  
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))  {   
    //Tells you if its all ok  
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory $user";
}else{   
    //Gives and error if its not  
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";  
} 

mysqli_close($db_link);
?>
```

So after your all help, i managed to get this code to work. But now the image is upload with its name duplicated such as image.jpgimage.jpg. How can i fix that so that it would be imageuser.jpg where the user is the current session user stored in `$user`?

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php - You've some parts missing. Plus, `$_FILES['uploadedfile']` that's not the same name as the others.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: This is what i get when i add the error reporting: Warning: basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/Project/upload.php on line 8 Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/Project/upload.php on line 21 Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.

Comment: Go through the manual. You'll see that you have things missing for your `$_FILES` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved  
$target = __DIR__ . "image/Profile_Pic/";
if (!file_exists($target)) {
    mkdir($target);
}
$target = $target . $_FILES['photo']['name'];
```

basename works on complete path's, so You should use it that way.

also move_uploaded_file should use $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] instead of just $_FILES['photo']

Comment: Now im just getting that the file could not be uploaded, no other error.

Comment: I'd guess that You have a problem with writing file to directory You've provided ...

Check your directory with function is_writable('image/Profile_Pic/');

Comment: apparently, i don't have permission. How would i fix that if im running apache on linux vm?

Comment: First check if file even exists:
`$target = __DIR__ . '/image/Profile_Pic/';
if (! file_exists($target) ) {
    mkdir($target);
}`
go on with your code

Comment: I've updated code above.

`__DIR__` constant is directory from which You run the script

Comment: You can make dir writable. On linux use command in shell: `chmod -R a+w /var/www/html/Project/image/Profile_Pic/`

Comment: I got the file to upload thank you, but i noticed that the file is duplicated. As in for example, my file DarkVader.jpg gets uploaded as DarkVader.jpgDarkVader.jpg, how would i change it so that such does nto happen?

Comment: Update Your code in Question or paste it on http://pastebin.com/ and provide here a link, because this code won't work now.
`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['name'], $target)` should be `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)` for example

Answer (score 0):

```
$target = "image/Profile_Pic/";  
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);  


$target = $target . $_FILES['photo']['name'];
```

This is why. You assign name twice to `$target` variable.

Delete last line and don't use `basename()`, because it's pointless in this code.